# ns2 rebroadcasting packet when timer is expired

Tags: timer, ns2

i need to rebroadcast packet when a waiting timer is expired, i follow steps defined at [How to add timer in aodv using ns2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673153/how-to-add-timer-in-aodv-using-ns2/38700499#38700499) , i define agent and timer classes; the cross reference; initialization of timer object in agent constructor; and finally  expire(Event*) for class B_suppression. when the execution reach 
    `agent->rebroadcast((Packet*)p, 0);` it abort with following message 'invalid SDVCAST packet type'. is casting from Event to Packet causes the problem?

```
class SDVCAST;

class B_suppression_Timer : public TimerHandler {
    friend class SDVCAST;
public:
    B_suppression_Timer (SDVCAST *s){agent = s;};
    virtual void expire (Event *p);
private:
    SDVCAST *agent;
};

class SDVCAST: public Agent
{ //define object from timer  
  B_suppression_Timer  bstimer;
}
//initialized timer in Constructor of the SDVCAST
SDVCAST::SDVCAST(nsaddr_t id) : Agent(PT_SDVCAST),
                bstimer(this){
}

// start timer
void
SDVCAST::weightepersistence(Packet *p, double delay){
  bstimer.resched(delay);
}


// define expire of bstimer
void
B_suppression_Timer::expire(Event *p){
    agent->rebroadcast((Packet*)p, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the new packet type `PT_SDVCAST` to `common/packet.h`

```
static const packet_t PT_ SDVCAST = 73;

        // insert new packet types here
static packet_t       PT_NTYPE = 74; // This MUST be the LAST one
.
.

                type == PT_SDVCAST)

.
.           
               name_[PT_SDVCAST]= "SDVCAST"
```

And maybe add `SDVCAST` to `tcl/lib/ns-packet.tcl`, `ns-default.tcl` , `ns-agent.tcl` etc.

---

EDIT : Answer to "Segmentation fault"

> "The implementation of the Packet data structure of NS2 does not math
>   the realities. The packet in ns2 simulation keeps all packet headers
>   for any protocols implemented in NS2. For example, a DSR routing
>   packet may keep DSDV, AODV, or even a PING application header. For
>   this reason, till today, a packet used in ns2 simulation, would have a
>   header size around 40~64KB. And NO packet would be deleted to release
>   the memory it holds until the end of the simulation. So for a typical
>   simulation with 100 nodes in ns2 around 1M packets exchanged (of
>   course, you may reuse the packets already being freed through
>   Packet::free(Packet*). To learn the implementation of it, please check
>   file common/packet{.h,.cc} ), you may hold 10% of it, 100K packets,
>   and you may use a memory at least 100K*64KB -> 6.4GB, which definitely
>   would crash your computer (even it is a super server)."

Etc. etc. See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ns2-and-aqua-sim-4175507630/#3

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/segmentation%20fault%20ns2/

Comment: Thanks for your response, already this steps done. i test the protocol so send and receive Hello message works OK. By debugging ns2 using eclipse i found casting from Event to Packet is not correct, not sure why!. So i has to make a transition to the Handler class and using handle function instead of TimerHandler and its' expire. Error message 'invalid SDVCAST packet type' disappeared, but unfortunately the execution stop and receive Segmentation fault error message.

Comment: `Segmentation fault` can appear when the simulation is too complex, or it simply cannot be handled with ns2. Sometimes an OS change can help.

Comment: Already i am installing ns 2.35 on Ubuntu 12.04. yes that right, i am trying to implement security layer on DV-Cast protocol who is complex by itself. Despite of reducing complexity through multiple functions.  it is necessary for me to use Timers, what i will do? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see my edited answer about "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Thanks @Knud Larsen, i make a transition to use Handler class instead of TimerHandler, by using next statement: Scheduler::instance().schedule(&bstimer, p->copy(), timeout); and this works fine. but i cannot check timer status during timer time.